# Save file in Windows protected folder

Tags: windows, vim

I'm using gVim and everytime I need to change my _vimrc file. But it is located in program files, so i can't save my edits there, because of system protection. So i copy the file to Desktop, change it, save, and move back to vim directory. Ahem. Is there any way to save directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to right-click gVim and click Run as Administrator.

Answer (score 6):

**Don't ever touch those files.** You are supposed to put your settings into `$HOME\_vimrc`.

Comment: How will vim find the file there?

Comment: @Fabricio `:h vimrc` It is where vim searches user configuration *by default*.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.exe => gvim --version => your LOCAL _vimrc & _gvimrc are in the output.
```